# Como isolar um fator de um resultado como um vetor?

Tags: r

Quero isolar um fator do resultado e deixa-lo como vetor para que possa utilizar esse fator em outra formula.

Exemplo:

```
library(drc)
data=S.alba
dados$Dose <- as.factor(dados$Dose)
alba.aov <- aov(DryMatter~Dose, data=dados)
summary(alba.aov)

            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)    
Dose         7 121.17  17.310   53.04 <2e-16 ***
Residuals   60  19.58   0.326                   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Eu gostaria de isolar somente o Sum Sq da Dose. Assim poderia utiliza-lo em outras formulas sem precisar ficar procurando o valor exato e alterando formula por formula.

Exemplo 2:

```
SumSqDose <- C(valor do Sum Sq alba.aov)
```

Ao invés de escrever uma formula assim: `(121,17/7)` Ficaria algo mais ou menos assim: `(SumSqDose/7)`

Alguém sabe como extrair esse valor sem precisar ficar buscando um por um?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A saída do `summary()` é um objeto lista. Entre as várias opções, aqui vão duas:

Opção 1:

```
  sm <- summary(alba.aov)

  sm <- unlist(sm)
  names(sm) # para indentificar o que você quer (no seu caso o elemento 3)
  sm[3]
```

Opção 2:

Você seleciona o primeiro elemento da lista, onde é salvo todas as informações, e usa a função `str()` por identificar todos elementos do objeto:

```
  sm <- summary(alba.aov)

  str(sm[[1]])
  sm[[1]]$'Sum Sq'[1]
```